# Cannot synch or add account to Outlook.com as ever before

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, sync, hotmail, outlook.com

Last year I used Outlook.com sync email setting and fetch my email messages from another account. However, when I try to retrieve messages as I did before, now I see that these settings are not available even I try using different options.

So, is these settings are not available anymore? Or is there anything that I can do to fetch email to my Outlook.com from another account. **I do not mean mail forwarding that works for the messages after forwarding, instead I need to synch emails.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niD98.png)

Comment: Is there anybody else who has ever used this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this feature?

[image]

If so, as shown in the text, Microsoft removed the ability to connect any other accounts to Outlook.com on May 10, 2021, but accounts connected before May 10, 2021, will continue to sync.

reference resources: [Add your other email accounts to Outlook.com](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-your-other-email-accounts-to-outlook-com-c5224df4-5885-4e79-91ba-523aa743f0ba)

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Thanks a lot amigo.